# SyntaxError: node_modules/angular2/ts/package.json: Unexpected token <

Tags: typescript, sails.js, angular

I develop sails app with angular 2 I setup ,but I got error in

```
SyntaxError: /home/mts/Desktop/sampleProject/appSails/node_modules/angular2/ts/package.json: Unexpected token <
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:430:27)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:129:29
at Array.forEach (native)
at requireAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:54:23
```

How can I solve that scenario how to up sails server ?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+%22Unexpected+token+%3C%22

Comment: couldn't found answer for my question in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem(which was also mine) is that angular2 is a clientside package,a package named `incluede-all` tries to  include all `node_module` files within a directory for sails. i solved this problem by adding an array of clientsideDependencies to **`package.json`**

```
 "clientsideDependencies": [  
      "angular2","zone.js","rxjs"
   ],
```

then i forked `include-all` package and write a code to pass this packages

here is my [fork](https://github.com/semirturgay/include-all)

you can use this fork it works without any problem just change the source of `include-all` at `package.json`  to :

```
"include-all": "https://github.com/semirturgay/include-all.git"
```

then run  `npm install` to update `include-all`

Comment: `include-all": "~0.1.6` already added my `package.json` to  but i can't solve my error.

Comment: as is explained in answer change `"include-all": "~0.1.6"` with `"include-all": "https://github.com/semirturgay/include-all.git" ` and also add this`"clientsideDependencies": [  
      "angular2","zone.js","rxjs"
   ],` to package.json Than run `npm install`

Comment: help me build sample sails project with angular2 in github.